# SDL2 - show a tooltip at the cursor that displays RGB of the pixel under the cursor?

Tags: sdl, sdl2, mouse

I'm writing an SDL2 program, in which I create a `SDL_CreateWindow` and get its `SDL_GetWindowSurface`, then I prepare some pixel updates on a separate `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` and `SDL_BlitSurface` the result to the window surface before I `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` it to the screen.

I would like to have a mouse tooltip feature that would display a dynamic tooltip at the cursor position with some information (such as RGB info of the pixel under the mouse). But the tooltip display should be separate from the pixels of the window surface, not blended into it. Is it possible to do that with SDL2? If so, how would a minimal working example look like? (I googled around but did not see any examples.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered getting the pixel RGB value of the pixel under the mouse pointer, of the SDL_Surface generated with the SDL_CreateRGBSurface() function, generate an SDL_Texture with the information gathered, which is then finally rendered to the window?

Comment: @Daniel_1985 as a workaround I ended up doing pretty much that. Reading out the pixels of the screen surface after all updates have been blitted to it, and then rendering ttf text right onto the window surface next to the mouse position. Since the window surface is overwritten every cycle, it does not screw up the continuity of updates for the content surface.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to post an answer to your question, containing what you did to solve the question. Also don't forget to, after 1-2 days, mark the answer as the correct one.